# is it possible to split column from specific element in list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have tried to transform the data frame into the list like this.

here is the data frame before transformation.

```
df_gr = df_com.groupby(['Publication_Year_x', 'UPC', 'CPC']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
df_gr_peryear = df_gr.replace(0, '', regex=True)

df_gr_peryear
```

[image: the data frame]

and here is the list that i have tried with this code

```
list_allyear = [(list(i), v) for i, v in df_gr_peryear.stack().iteritems()]
list_allyear = pd.DataFrame(list_allyear, columns=["MOC", "count"])
list_allyear
```

here is the result

[image]

but I would like to split it just only the first element in all rows. the expected result will be

```
year  MOC         count
1971 [136,-]
1971 [136, A01D] 
.
.
1972 [231, H01L]    5
```

I have tried the `pd.DataFrame(list_allyear.MOC.values.tolist())` but it splits all elements that contain in the rows

Comment: One question - Is not problem mixed empty values with numeric? Not better omit `df_gr_peryear = df_gr.replace(0, '', regex=True)` ?

Comment: yes, there is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simplified your code where you can use `fill_value=''` instead `replace` and then creating a dictionaries for list comprehension to have a final `DataFrame`:

```
cols = ['Publication_Year_x', 'UPC', 'CPC']
s = df_com.groupby(cols).size().unstack(fill_value='').stack()

L = [{'year': idx[0], 'MOC': list(idx[1:]), 'count': vals} for idx, vals in s.items()]
list_allyear = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Comment: @HookIm - You are welcome! Be free upvote solution too :)

Comment: @pygo - Thank you.